# Derivative of matrix wrt. its square

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $F$ be an arbitrary real square matrix, $C=F^{\sf T}F$, and $F_2 = FF$. Is there any way to express
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial C}$$
or
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial F_2}$$ analytically?

If it helps the answer can be specialized to $3\times3$ matrices. The case of $1\times1$ matrices is solvable by substitution, but I don't see the basic idea how to generalize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial C}$ is defined only if $F$ is a function of $C$, that is if we can define a bijection $F\rightarrow C=F^TF$. Note that $C$ is a symmetric $\geq 0$ matrix ($C\in S⁺$).

The simplest method is to consider the function $f:C\in S⁺\rightarrow \sqrt{C}\in S⁺$.

More generally, we can choose an orthogonal matrix $O$ (fixed) and consider the function $g:C\in S⁺\rightarrow O\sqrt{C}$.

These functions have a derivative when $C$ is invertible (cf. my post in [Derivative (or differential) of symmetric square root of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540361/derivative-or-differential-of-symmetric-square-root-of-a-matrix/541052#541052))

$Df_C(H)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{C}}He^{-t\sqrt{C}}dt$

$Dg_C(H)=ODf_C(H)$ where $H$ is a symmetric matrix.

EDIT 1.

Part 2. For the second function $F^2$, let $Z=\{C\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}); spectrum(C)\subset \mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{0\}\}$. Then we can define a function $f:C\in Z\rightarrow f(C)\in Z$ with $f(C)^2=C$. Indeed, there is a unique matrix $X\in Z$ s.t. $X^2=C$.

EDIT 2. Let $Z^+=\{C\in Z; \text{the eigenvalues of } $C$ \text{ are distinct}\}$. Since $Z^+$ is open, its  tangent space is $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and, again, the derivative of $f:C\in Z^+\rightarrow f(C)\in Z^+$ is:

$Df_C(H)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{C}}He^{-t\sqrt{C}}dt$ where $H\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: (Don't have enough "reputation" to comment your answer in the linked question) Does the formula for $Df_c(H)$ have a special name? I absolutely don't see where it comes from.

Comment: cf. my EDIT 3 in the reference above.